# Forward All Except Filter in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I'm using Gmail Forwarding to forward all messages to another account. However I have about 50 email addresses in a filter that I do not want forwarded.

I don't want to mark these messages as spam, because they're important emails, but just don't want them forwarded.

Is there an advanced filter to forward all messages sent to the account except those that match this particular filter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always negate your existing filter - I assume it's in the form `from:(address1@gmail.com OR address2@gmail.com)` and so on. If that's the case:

1. Disable the setting that is forwarding all your mail (Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Forwarding > "Disable Forwarding").
2. Create a new filter that looks like the following (notice the dash before **from:**):
   [image]
3. Therefore, only mail that doesn't match these conditions will be forwarded.

EDIT:

You can create a filter by entering your search first and clicking the arrow for "Show search options": [image]

Then click the "Create filter with this search" button: [image]

Comment: As of 27Jan2015, if you click in the box that has the current filter text, it takes you out of the Settings / Filters / Create a new filter (or Settings / Filters / Edit) dialog. I have not found a way to modify what is created initially by filling in the form!

Comment: @J.Merrill that has nothing to do with this question, and as of at least 2018/2019, you click 'continue'

Comment: regarding your conditional. James says that your conditional didn't work but this one did `from:(-(address1@gmail.com OR address2@gmail.com))` worked for him

Comment: this solution is amazing but doesn't seem that scalable, see related q https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123576/in-gmail-is-there-a-scalable-way-to-forward-all-email-except  I wonder if this one is more scalable https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73962/how-to-get-gmail-to-forward-all-mail-except-from-a-certain-address

Answer (score 2):

The solution above didn't work for me (Feb 2015). However, this solution did work:

```
from:(-(address1@gmail.com OR address2@gmail.com))
```

Comment: the question was about forwarding email not about a conditional

Comment: you should make that a comment

Answer (score -1):

For my case the following one worked - ( I added this on the field "Has the Word")

(from:(-(address@gmail.com OR address@gmail.com)))

Answer (score -1):

In the field "Has the words" alright but no need for the "from" and delimit addresses with {}, like this:
-{one_mail@gmail.com OR two_mail@gmail.com OR three_mail@gmail.com}
The "-" upfront makes it Has not the words and discards these addresses.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).